# keyfile issue in gcs-connector library

Tags: java, hadoop, google-cloud-platform, connector

I am trying to use gcs-connector library in java as is explained here at https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/master/gcs/INSTALL.md .
I have added following properties in core-site.xml as mentioned in the link above

```
fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl
fs.gs.project.id
google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable
google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile
```

But I am getting error as `P12 key file may not be specified at the same time as credentials via configuration.`  although I have passed this parameter.
[Can see in local value is assigned to variable as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM50q.png)

As can be see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSawH.png) code is failing because it is trying to check non null string (as can be seen in the attached screenshot ).
Although it is able to read value from config but `Strings.isNullOrEmpty(options.getServiceAccountKeyFile())` is failing the code.

Requesting someone to please help us with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you’re misunderstanding the `Strings.isNullOrEmpty` function: it isn’t to check if it’s a non-null value, is to check if it’s a null value; it’s throwing the error because you already gave the value, so it seems that you’re trying to sign in twice. You have to pick either the Service Account Private Key Id, a Service Account email or an Account Key